# Flash loan compile error with function() external payable

Tags: solidity, defi, flash-loans

I am attempting to compile a flash loan contract. I am having issues with the external payable function. I've tried adding fallback or receive as the error message suggests but I still receive the same error. Is there a particular way this line of code needs to be written? All help appreciated. Thanks.

```
contract FlashLoanReceiverBase is IFlashLoanReceiver {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address constant ETHADDRESS = 0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE;

    ILendingPoolAddressesProvider public addressesProvider = ILendingPoolAddressesProvider(
        0x24a42fD28C976A61Df5D00D0599C34c4f90748c8
    );

    function() external payable {}

    function transferFundsBackToPoolInternal(address _reserve, uint256 _amount)
        internal
    {
        address payable core = addressesProvider.getLendingPoolCore();
        transferInternal(core, _reserve, _amount);
    }

    function transferInternal(
        address payable _destination,
        address _reserve,
        uint256 _amount
    ) internal {
        if (_reserve == ETHADDRESS) {
            //solium-disable-next-line
            _destination.call.value(_amount)("");
            return;
        }

        IERC20(_reserve).transfer(_destination, _amount);
    }

    function getBalanceInternal(address _target, address _reserve)
        internal
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        if (_reserve == ETHADDRESS) {
            return _target.balance;
        }

        return IERC20(_reserve).balanceOf(_target);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Where is the payable function you are referring to, it's not in the code you shared?

Comment: Please just edit your question to include all the relevant information, in a formatted way

Comment: Um, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why do you have a line `function() external payable {}`? Do you simply want to be able to receive Ethers in the contract?

Comment: It's part of a lengthy arbitrage contract. I've tried a couple of different contracts and i always get a parse error telling me to use fallback function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Solidity 0.6.0 or above, instead of using

```
 function() external payable {}
```

You should use new keyword **receive**

```
receive() external payable { }
```

Used as a fallback function after receiving ether

Comment: Thanks very much :) I will try that, much appreciated :-)